# Windows 10 upgrade leads to grub rescue, boot-repair dosen't work

Tags: dual-boot, 15.04, grubrescue, windows-10

I've fallen victim to windows' aggressive handling of boot-ups. I have **Ubuntu** and **Windows 7** side by side on my PC, and after I started the upgrade to **Windows 10**, I couldn't boot to continue the upgrade. Booting results only in Grub rescue prompt.

I've tried using boot-repair with no results (http://paste.ubuntu.com/12243604/) and I tried repairing the MBR with windows 10 installation iso, and it still doesn't fix the problem.

Since then I tried fixing the problem manually by enabling EFI in BIOS and i tried running the command **`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`** in Windows 10 installer, but nothing have helped so far.

I've also been looking around in the grub rescue menu, and all partitions shows as msdos partitions. And I can't find any boot partition through ls (hdx,msdosx), since they all show as unknown filesystems.

Both OS are 64-bit, ubuntu version is 15.04.

---

SOLVED: I managed to solve this through the windows 10 startup USB. I went into the command prompt and wrote the following commands:

bootrec /RebuildBcd
bootrec /fixMbr
bootrec /fixboot
Exit
(src: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows)

That wasnt enough though, as I continued to fiddle with he troubleshooting menu in the windows 10 repair menu. I turned UEFI off and after some random fiddling and being stubborn, the upgrade process has resumed.

Do note that this nukes ubuntu from the boot order!

Comment: @David6... done.

Comment: If/when you get the 'upgrade' to complete (and you have 'activated' Windows 10), start over. And use the default UEFI settings. See link below on dual boot install. *This assume you also re-install Ubuntu.*

Comment: @KhaaL with your explanations you restored the whole grub as it was before? I have the same issues and dont want to loose or reinstall ubuntu. Thx!

Comment: @OblTobl I never restored ubuntu, I nuked grub completly.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this through the windows 10 startup USB. I went into the command prompt and wrote the following commands:

bootrec /RebuildBcd bootrec /fixMbr bootrec /fixboot Exit (src: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows)

That wasnt enough though, as I continued to fiddle with he troubleshooting menu in the windows 10 repair menu. I turned UEFI off and after some random fiddling and being stubborn, the upgrade process has resumed.

Do note that this nukes ubuntu from the boot order!

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that **Windows 7** doesn't use UEFI, and **Windows 10** certainly does.

The **Windows 10** 'install/upgrade' utility (*I really hesitate to use that word*) somehow tricks the PC/laptop into changing its behaviour 'during the install/re-boot process'. It also overrides the boot order, with the 'failsafe' "Press key to boot from CD/DVD" to fix its own mistakes.

That means you need a quite recent BIOS or .. (*You already found out what!*)

PS: *It also means picking legacy boot, the correct boot order, etc. isn't necessarily going to help very much.*

---

Your problems are:

- You need to complete the 'upgrade' to gain the 'activated' **Windows 10** license. The only shortcut here is *buy a license*, and just install **Windows 10**.
- You likely need to not go back to a 'factory install' of **Windows 7** (as supplied by vendor), then start over. If you had an OEM install, then that brand of installer DVD (obtained/borrowed from wherever) will get you back to installed/activated with **Windows 7**. Then hunt down any missing drivers (from PC vendor's website), and don't forget to get all Windows updates. *Then try again.*
- However, after 'succeeding' you will still want to do a 'clean install' of Windows 10. So start by getting the ISO file and creating an install USB (using Rufus: https://rufus.akeo.ie/), for any upgrades or re-installs. Lastly, follow these instructions: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score -2):

Use Windows 10 in a Virtualbox environment if you have sufficient memory.  Never use Windows as a your primary OS unless you absolutely have to.  It is also a lot easier to backup your Windows 10 Virtualbox, all you have to do is copy a folder to an external drive.  Furthermore, you can use your Windows 10 virtual machine on ANY computer with Virtualbox.  Just my humble opinion.